# Map matching of one sided road data to two sided road data

Tags: qgis, postgis, buffer, overlay, map-matching

we use **BOS method (Goodchild and Hunter,1997)** for checking the positional accuracy of test map dataset by buffering around the reference dataset and then check for percentage coverage of test dataset in that buffer.

In case while comparing the road dataset there is a possibility that one dataset contains roads represented as a single side (bidirectional traffic flow on the same road) and same road in the second dataset is having two sides (unidirectional traffic flow).  Please suggest how can we compare such datasets.

Answer (score 3):

I've performed this kind of [analysis a few years ago](https://anitagraser.com/2013/12/15/osm-quality-assessment-with-qgis-positional-accuracy/). To solve the issue of comparing oneway information in different road datasets, we used a routing-based approach, which checks if oneways in dataset A are also contained in dataset B. The idea is described in this video of [my presentation at FOSS4G 2013](https://youtu.be/RXr4s9MILOw?t=16m27s).

[image]

You can read more about this (and about how to check turn restrictions) in: 
[Graser, A., Straub, M., & Dragaschnig, M. (2014). Towards an open source analysis toolbox for street network comparison: indicators, tools and results of a comparison of OSM and the official Austrian reference graph. Transactions in GIS, 18(4), 510-526. doi:10.1111/tgis.12061.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/tgis.12061/abstract) ([preprint](https://underdark.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/preprint_tgis_foss4g2013_graseretal.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is there any method to extract such dissimilar features from two objects. Or otherwise some heuristic approach must be designed for the same.